# Prevent high swap : apache configuration for server with high traffic site

Tags: linux, apache-2.4

I own a server that hosts a high traffic site that serves 800 - 1400 users at a given time. These users usually stays for more than 5 minutes (given the nature of the site where users usually download large files).

What I noticed is that the server runs out of SWAP every 48 hours yet my server is only using 5-11% of the memory. I would like to seek advice on what changes should I make to the Apache configuration to prevent it from happening.

My apache configuration is as follows :

```
keepalive: Off 
keepalivetimeout: 5
maxclients: 2500    
maxkeepaliverequests: 200     
maxrequestsperchild: 10000  
maxspareservers: 10  
minspareservers: 5     
serverlimit: 2600 
serversignature: Off     
servertokens: Full  
startservers: 5 
timeout: 300
```

Server specs :

```
Intel XEON E5-1620v2
64 GB DDR3 ECC 1600MHz 
2x2000GB
```

Comment: Apache has most likely nothing to do with your system using swap. The most likely reason is your web application. Maybe it fetches large amounts of data to memory from the database or so. Give detailed information on your application infrastructure and we might be able to help.

Comment: I'm using htaccess RewriteCond for large file downloads. Do you think it's what's causing the large swap?

Comment: No, rewritecond has nothing to do with this. How many requests are you serving in parallel ? What memory limit did you set in PHP and how much memory is using a request in your webapp ?

Comment: 169 requests/sec - 56.8 MB/second - 344.0 kB/request
| 32M memory limit in PHP

Comment: Can you please post memory usage stats, hard to know what's happening without that.

Comment: If you are running out of memory and apache is the "reason" - apache is configured such that it can consume more memory than exists. It's also probably unable to handle the requests fast enough because there is a bottleneck in the app such as the db, or simply inefficient code. `I'm using htaccess` - that's one things to stop doing, even [apache's docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html) don't recommend using `.htaccess` files unless you "have to".

Comment: The apache settings posted are very aggressive for even that hardware.  Not letting apache go wild should get your memory usage down and increase overall throughput.

Answer (score 1):

Try optimising operation before considering hardware upgrades.

Else, I'd generally recommend you enable oom killer, as it would kill any process that gets close to consuming all of the servers ram. Of course, you would then need an updated way to restart apache again (eg daemontools).

But before that, I suppose you can look into setting the MaxClients directive for apache. This limits the amount of requests apache will service at a time and queue the others. For prefork, this limits the amount of child processes. For worker, it limits the amount of threads available to serve requests.

"Maxclients $number" is the syntax and you can experiment with the MaxClients number to see how high you can set it without consuming too many server resources.

Of course, this advice is based on the assumption that you have already pinpointed apache as the cause of your memory problem.

Comment: Blindly throwing more hardware at the problem, or relying on oom-killer is a band-aide fix. If, for example, each apache thread consumes 50mb, and apache is configured to allow 2600 servers, the server needs to have 130GB of ram for that config. Apache should _not_ be configured to expect there to be more ram than there is in the first place; it should be dropping requests itself if it is infact resource limited long before being oom-ed.

Comment: Limiting maxclients is going to limit performance. Each of my suggestions have levels of preference.

Comment: `the server runs out of SWAP every 48 hours **yet my server is only using 5-11% of the memory**` - You chastised the now-deleted answerer for suggesting to reduce swappiness, yet your primary suggestion appears to be add more ram (if I'm misreading the very first line of your answer, please do clarify). It's quite likely that 128GB with the given config is not enough memory - so just how ludicrously should the server be speced =)? To state the obvious "800 - 1400 users at a given time" does not mean "800 - 1400 concurrent requests" - limiting max clients may well have no noticeable impact.

Comment: Check the audit log. The OP only added the part about "5-11% of the memory" 21 hours ago. In light of the new information, that now makes all prior answers redundant. As for your point about hardware, of course the OP should explore software solutions first. Limiting maxclients would be a good idea to see if the resulting config can handle the traffic.

Comment: I hadn't noticed that was "new" info - the main point still stands though that the (estimated) amount of memory apache is configured to expect in the question far exceeds what the server has (and would require a top-end server). `of course the OP should explore software solutions first` - it's not obvious from the answer that's your suggestion, at least to me quite the contrary: `Ideally you should upgrade your server ... I suppose you can look into [changing the config]`.

Comment: Edited for you.

Answer (score 1):

1. Cut off swap completely since using it is probably making things worse.
2. Cut `maxrequestsperchild` and `maxclients` way down.  Start by lopping a zero off the end and see how it goes.  From there you may want to cut them in half a few times.
3. Implement an oom killer.